# Send push notification to mobile device from website

Tags: php, android, ios, amazon-ec2, push-notification

I am hosting my website on an amazon ec2 instance. When someone fills a form i want to receive a push notification on my mobile device containing the information submitted. Is it possible to achieve this without making an app?

Comment: Complete question -> I am hosting my website on an amazon ec2 instance. When someone fills a form i want to receive a push notification on my mobile device containing the information submitted. i would preferably want to use php as i don't know any other backend languages at the moment. Is it possible to achieve this without making an app? I have already tried Amazon SNS but i think it needs an app to function. Free solutions are appriciated

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/Ph3nol/NotificationPusher)

Comment: on iOS you need an app to register for and receive the push notification.  You cannot send directly to the device

Comment: not exactly the solution, but if you have push notification enabled for emails, you can send yourself an email each time there's a form submission.

Comment: ^oh thats actually a nice idea. I can create a separate id and enable notifications just for that id, that way i wont be bugged by other random emails. Will work for now, till i get myself to learn app dev. thx :)

Comment: Haves you tried the MBaaS Parse? They got a simple and nice SDK for sending and receiving PushNotificaiton from both phones and the web. https://www.parse.com